Error resolving to MinIO end point from .NET code
I am doing a PoC to use MinIO as an object storage solution in our On Premise infrastructure.
I have created the MinIO server and created a bucket manually and uploaded a file in that bucket. So far so good.
However as I try to access that bucket/create bucket using the API, I am facing issues.
I tried using .NET code and I am facing issues with end point. My Installation window shows the following:
API: http://XXX.X.XX.XX:YYYY  http://127.0.0.1:YYYY
RootUser: XXXXXXXXX
RootPass: XXXXXXXXX
WebUI: http://XXX.X.XX.XX:ZZZZ http://127.0.0.1:ZZZZ
RootUser: XXXXXXXXX
RootPass: XXXXXXXXX
CLI: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc.html#quickstart
$ mc alias set 'myminio' 'http://XXX.X.XX.XX:YYYY' 'XXX.X.XX.XX' 'XXX.X.XX.XX'

Also I ran the following commands -
mc.exe alias set AAAAAA http://127.0.0.1:YYYY XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX

However - I am not able to connect to the MinIO using .NET program
Here is my .NET code
IMinioClient minio = new MinioClient()
                    .WithEndpoint(endpoint)
                    .WithCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
                    .WithSSL()
                    .Build();

It works when I put the end point as - play.min.io.
Can any body please advice?
